# connection to powerbi workspace using python

Tags: python, server, powerbi, power-bi-report-server, azure-analysis-services

I am trying to automate the model incremental refresh in PowerBI. I connected the workspace in SSMS using Analysis services option. Partitions are created for each table. Now I want to do the incremental refresh for particular partition using python. I am using this script, but getting the error on connection string, help me on this.

**Script:**

```
import requests

# Replace these variables with your actual values
tenant_id = "tenant_id"
client_id = "client_id"
client_secret = "client_secret"
server_name = "hostnorthcentralus$$9-0$0"
database_name = "database_name"
table_name = "table_name"
partition_name = "partition_name"

refresh_script = f'''
{{
  "refresh": {{
    "type": "full",
    "objects": [
      {{
        "database": "{database_name}",
        "table": "{table_name}",
        "partition": "{partition_name}"
      }}
    ]
  }}
}}
'''
token_url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token"
token_data = {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": client_id,
    "client_secret": client_secret,
    "resource": "https://*.asazure.windows.net/"
}
response = requests.post(token_url, data=token_data)
access_token = response.json().get("access_token")

if access_token is None:
    print("Failed to obtain access token.")
    exit(1)

base_url = f"https://{server_name}.asazure.windows.net"
refresh_url = f"{base_url}/v1.0/{database_name}/refresh"

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

response = requests.post(refresh_url, headers=headers, data=refresh_script)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Partition refresh request submitted successfully.")
else:
    print("Failed to submit the partition refresh request.")
```

**Error:**

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='hostnorthcentralus$$9-0$0.asazure.windows.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1.0/database_name/refresh (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021DBB566C20>: Failed to resolve 'hostnorthcentralus$$9-0$0.asazure.windows.net' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)"))
```

**NOTE**: hidden some characters in the server name with **$** as posting it in public forum.